when drawing a graph, what does f(-x) = -f(x) mean?
The question I am working on is this: Sketch the graph of a function that satisfies all of the given conditions. Note that you need to make ONE graph that satisfies all the given conditions f'(x)>0 if x<2, f'(x)<0 if x>2, f'(2)=0, limx approaches infinity f(x)=1, f(-x)=-f(x) f''(x)<0 if 0<x<3, f''(x)>0 if x>3.
If you wouldn't mind including a drawing of the graph that would be great. I understand the other conditions it's just the one in bold that is giving me trouble.

Tip. Experiment with this: Pick $(0, 0)$ and four other points on the right side, like $(1, -2), (2, -1), (3, 1), (4, 2)$. What other points must be there, based on the bold condition? Connect the dots and see if you can figure out what the general effect of the condition is.

Consider a special case of $x=1$. The constraint means that $f(1)$ and $f(-1)$ have the same absolute value but opposite signs.

A function that satisfies $f(-x)=-f(x)$ is called an "odd function," if you want a term to search up. Such functions will look like they're being reflected across the $y$-axis and $x$-axis in sequence, as if each were a mirror, since
$$
f(1) = -f(-1)
\qquad
f(2) = -f(-2)
\qquad
\cdots
$$
and so on. Another way to think about it is taking the graph for $x>0$ of $f(x)$, and then rotating it $180^\circ$ about the origin. Some basic examples of such functions include

$f(x) = x^n$ for any odd $n$
$f(x) = \sin x$
$f(x) = \operatorname{sign}(x) = \begin{cases}
+1, & x > 0 \\
-1, & x < 0 \end{cases}$
$f(x) = \tan x$

You can play with them in a Desmos demo here. Enter a function for $f(x)$, and a version of it made "odd" will be created for the function $g(x)$ by the rule
$$
g(x) \stackrel{\text{def.}}{=}
\begin{cases}
f(x), & x \ge 0 \\
-f(-x), & x < 0
\end{cases}
$$
For instance, for $f(x) = \cos x$,

or $f(x) = x^2-2x$,

or $f(x) = \sin x$, where $f$ looks exactly like $g$ because they're the same thing:


$f(-x)=-f(x)$ means that the graph is symmetric relatively to the origin.
For example, $x\rightarrow x^{3}$ satisfies this property.
This is often described as an odd fonction.
